How to bind a component instance in a type-safe manner in Svelte 5?
I'm following the tutorial provided by the Svelte team in their website!
There is this section in the tutorial that basically explains how we can expose certain functionalities from a custom component: Tutorial Page
I get the concept but when i'm trying to implement it with typescript i get no type safety out of the box!
Example:
<!-- text.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
let content = $state('Hello');

export function getContent() {
    return content;
}
</script>

<p>{content}</p>

<!-- app.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
import Text from './text.svelte';

let text;

$effect(() => {
    console.log(text.getContent());
});
</script>

<Text bind:this={text} />

in the example, type of the text variable is any!
also typing the variable like this does not give me access to getContent method:
let text: Text;


Edit: Since PR 2553 additional changes may no longer be necessary.
In Svelte 5 components are functions and you can get the type of an instance via their ReturnType:
let text: ReturnType<typeof Text>;

